# ErrorHandler de Angular no funciona con métodos asíncronos

Tags: angular, typescript, web, clase, asincronismo

Estoy intentando centralizar el manejo de errores a través del ErrorHandler de Angular. Para esto me basé en la documentación oficial:
https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler

Hasta aquí, todo bien: las excepciones que arrojo en la aplicación, son recibidas sin problemas por la clase que definí para tal propósito (**GlobalErrorHandler**), la cual implementa la clase **ErrorHandler**.

El problema surge al lanzar un error personalizado, por ejemplo, de la siguiente clase:

```
export class UIError extends Error{
  constructor(message: string) {
      super(message);
      Object.setPrototypeOf(this, UIError.prototype);
  }
}
```

a través de la siguiente sentencia:

```
throw new UIError('message');
```

Lo que sucede es que si lanzo la excepción desde un método asincrónico, Angular realiza un casting del tipo **UIError** a **Error** al momento del ser procesada por el **GlobalErrorHandler**, no pudiendo diferenciar de esta manera el tipo de error que voy a tratar, y por otra parte tampoco me permitiría acceder a las propiedades adicionales que pueda definir en mi clase de error personalizada.
En cambio, si lo ejecuto desde un método sincrónico funciona todo como se espera.
También funciona correctamente si capturo la excepción desde un bloque try/catch en el método asincrónico, pero justamente es lo que trato de evitar centralizando el manejo de los errores.

Les preparé un proyecto super sencillo, donde expongo los 3 casos anteriormente mencionados:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-global-errorhandler-test?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

- ¿Cómo podría lograr que esto no suceda en un método asincrónico?
  Sería conveniente poder implementar una solución en común para ambos
  casos, ya que de otra manera, dejaría abierta la posibilidad de
  cometer errores en la implementación por no haberse comprobado
  previamente la sincronía/asincronía del método.
- Por último ¿Por qué sucede esto?

Les agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda que puedan darme. Ya busqué en muchos lugares y hasta ahora no logro dar con la solución.

Saludos.

Comment: Usa en tu handler algo cómo `if (error instanceof UIError || (error.rejection && error.rejection instanceof UIError)`. Si pones un `console.log(error)` en tu handler te darás cuenta que el error que se produce un método asincrónico es pasado al ErrorHandler en una especie de wrapper que contiene el contexto en el que se produjo el error. Dentro de este objeto, se guarda el error en la propiedad `rejection`.

Comment: Excelente Jaime! Es tal cual lo mencionás. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si bien había inspeccionado dentro del error por consola, no pude diferenciar el wrapper que mencionás.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando el error viene de una promesa es una instancia de la clase `Error` la cual tiene dentro otras propiedadades, una de ellas es `rejected` la cual en tu caso tiene un objeto de tipo `UIError`.

```
handleError(error: any) {
        if ((error.rejection ?? error) instanceof UIError) {
          alert('Es un error de UI');
        } else if (error instanceof Error) {
          alert('Es un error genérico');
        }
      }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Lobos!! Es muy clara tu respuesta y solucionó mi problema.
Había llegado a la definición de la interfaz, pero solo encontré las propiedades message, stack y name. Posiblemente rejection viene de otra clase/interfaz. 
Voy a buscar más sobre el tema.